# SQLite, Python - Retrieve secondary field based on python list items

Tags: python, sqlite

How do I retrieve a specific field based on items in a python list?

I currently have a python list of entry numbers that originated from my `2014 Data Table` in SQLite. At the end of my python function, I need to retrieve the people that the entry numbers are associated to.

So for example, I have a list of 5 entry numbers:

```
Entry List

Entry#
1045
1794
2398
3476
6312
```

What I want:

```
Entry#    Person
1045      Jim
1794      Carol
2398      Bill
3476      Mary
6312      Viola
```

I need to get the Person that these entry numbers are associated to. The data is in the `2014 Data Table`, but I cant quite figure out the SQL query for that.

The closest I've gotten is:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

sqlite_file = 'researchdata.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor() 

for i in Entry_list:
    result = c.execute('SELECT Person FROM 2014Data WHERE EntryID = ?', i)
    result_list = list(result)
    print(result_list)
# print()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It would help if you show which lib you are using to access sqlite (your import lines at the top) and the result you are getting now and the one you want to get

Comment: Hi @Marco, I added it to my question. thanks for the feedback! `import sqlite3
    import csv
    
    sqlite_file = 'researchdata.db'
    conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
    c = conn.cursor() `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

Entry_list = [1,2]

sqlite_file = 'researchdata.db'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c = conn.cursor()

for i in Entry_list:
    sql = "SELECT Person FROM _2014Data WHERE EntryID = %i" % (i)
    result = c.execute(sql)
    record = result.fetchone()
    print(record[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I keep getting this error: `TypeError: %i format: a number is required, not str
` The list I'm using is full of numbers as strings. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: and when I use %s and try to print out a list of the 45 results I just get 45 blank `[]`

Comment: I got it now. To get both columns together I had to use `"SELECT Person, EntryID FROM _2014Data WHERE EntryID = %s" % (i)` Thank you so much @Marco!